# What are the causes for a JSP web session to be reset other than timeout or session.invalidate()?

Tags: java, jsp, http, session

I have a bug in my JSP application.  My session is cleared after post:

```
    YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', Url, callback, postData);
```

Before that call, all attributes are there, but after it they are lost.
I want to know what may be the reason for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http session is maintained by the web server/browser by adding headers to the request/response that contains a [`SESSION_ID`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID). The headers may be lost on the network before they reach the web server or web client. The web server creates a new session automatically if the request doesn't have the session ID.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. SESSION_ID is not changing but the session attributes are lost. Any ideas?

Comment: On localhost it is working, but over a network the bug appears.

Comment: Session attributes are not available if the new session is created. Check the session ID when attributes are presented and when they are lost. If you read the link I've posted you should be aware where a browser stores the session ID and how it's transferred to the server.

Comment: I printed the session attributes and session id before post and after. Session id is identical but attributes are lost.